# Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 7 was incorrect on entry to DGELSD when including both Armadillo and Open3D in cpp

Tags: c++, armadillo, blas, intel-mkl, open3d

I am working on a cpp-project based on Open3D and armadillo on Ubuntu18.04. After adding `Open3D::Open3D` to linked libraries, some functions from armadillo like `arma::inv(A)` and `arma::solve(X, A, B)` that requires Intel MKL don't work and output error message like
**"Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 7 was incorrect on entry to DGELSD"**.

I've built a standalone program running linear regression that only calls functions in armadillo, but still when I include Open3D in CMakeLists, the program fails with the same error. I am wondering is there any compile flag I should specify when building Open3D, or any possible reason for it cause?

CPP program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;
using namespace std::chrono;

#define AVG_LEN (5ULL)

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::pair<size_t, arma::dmat::fixed<AVG_LEN, 3ULL>>> upload_info; 
    upload_info["A1b"].second.fill(1.0);
    auto it = upload_info.find("A1b");
    for (int i=0; i<AVG_LEN; ++i) {
        it->second.second(i, 0) = i*2;
        it->second.second(i, 2) = i+10;
        it->second.first++;
    }
    arma::vec2 X;
    arma::dmat::fixed<AVG_LEN, 3ULL> info(it->second.second);
    bool status = arma::solve(X, info.cols(0, 1), info.col(2));
    if (status)
        cout << "X: \n" << X << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Without including `Open3D::Open3D` in `target_link_libraries`, the output is correct as

```
X: 
   0.5000
  10.0000
```

But after including that, it just outputs an error message
`Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 7 was incorrect on entry to DGELSD.`

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and Open3D 0.16.1. I build Open3D from source by

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF \
    -DBUILD_GUI=OFF -DBUILD_WEBRTC=OFF -DBUILD_PYTHON_MODULE=OFF \
    -DGLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=ON -DWITH_OPENMP=ON \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$O3D_INSTALL_DIR ..
```

#### Additional information

Armadillo can be easily installed by `apt-get install -y liblapack-dev libarmadillo-dev`, it uses Blas to accelerate computation. I include Open3d in CMakeLists by

```
foreach(_target
  demo) # 
  add_executable(${_target} "${_target}.cpp")
  target_link_libraries(${_target} Open3D::Open3D
  ${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES})
endforeach()
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved by setting `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON`